# Unable to access span inside widget after page load

Tags: jquery

I want to use a third party widget, but I want to pull some data out of it to display in a bar at the top of my page. However, I can't seem to select the elements that are created in the DOM after the widget loads.

The widget itself is something to this effect before load:

```
<div class="widget-container">
  <div class="widget-container__widget"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://theirwebsite.com/theirJS.js" async>
</div>
```

And after load it looks like this in the DOM:

```
<div class="widget-container">
  <iframe src="http://theirwebsite.com"></iframe>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='some-data-container'>
         <span class='some-data'>This Data</span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access the 'some-data' span.

I've tried $(window).bind("load", function() and $(document).ready(function(){ to make sure that the code is firing after page load, but trying to access $('.some-data').text() gives me nothing.

Right now my js file is in this state:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  let dataGrab = $('.some-data').text();
  console.log(dataGrab);
});
```

What am I just completely missing?

Comment: $(".some-data") - you're not missing the period for the class selector, right?

Comment: You're right!  But that was a typo when I was writing this up, and my code is good...just checked!

Comment: Can you please include more of your Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: When is the widget being initialized?  And how is it being created?  Page load does not account for any ajax requests that may run to get data needed to build elements on the page.

Comment: @DavidPartyka I edited the post with the only js I have written at the moment.  I just started this app so there's not a whole lot going on yet.

Comment: @Taplar I just went back and see that I missed a line in the copy/paste, and there's a big fat async there when their script is called.  I edited the code above to reflect it.

Comment: I would try taking off that `async` then and see if anything changes, as a first step.  That `async` is going to tell the browser to load that resource asynchronously, so it is possible that the load could happen before that script is retrieved and finishes processing.

Comment: Try console.log($('.some-data').length)     // if the console returns '0' this means the widget hasn't loaded yet ---- do this as the first statement after the .bind() line (in your callback)

Comment: @Taplar Removing the async actually had no effect...

Comment: Then that sounds like their script is potentially doing some asynchronous logic to build their widget.  If that is true, without some insight into what the widget is, it would be hard for me to suggest to you a way to hook into their logic to wait for it to initialize the widget, short of using a setInterval of some kind, which is a last resort.

Comment: @Taplar here is the widget as it appears in the DOM in all of its glory: https://repl.it/repls/DaringReadyFonts